# Why can't I require(...) in a loop using browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

This works

```
require( './AppCtrl' );
```

but if I do

```
[ './AppCtrl' ].forEach( function( name ) {
    require( name );
});
```

it results in errors

```
_prelude.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './AppCtrl's @  _prelude.js:1s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ index.js:48 @ index.js:3s @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:11../config @ app.js:22s @ _prelude.js:1e @ _prelude.js:1(anonymous function) @ _prelude.js:1
 angular.js:12416 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=AppCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
at assertArg (angular.js:1795)
at assertArgFn (angular.js:1805)
at angular.js:9069
at setupControllers (angular.js:8133)
at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8173)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7637)
at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7512)
at angular.js:1660
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15878)
```

for my end goal I'd like to be able to do something like this pseudocode

```
 foreach  name {
     angular.module(...).controller( require( name ) );
 }
```

but right now I'm not sure why I can't require files inside the loop?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: because I think it's ridiculous to have to manually require every single module, there's a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: Requiring everything everywhere is a code smell of course, maybe there's something wrong with your code? However, you should just combine those modules that you repeat everywhere in a large module, and only import that everywhere. Not use an array and a loop.

Comment: @Bergi more like I was trying to see if I could get more Spring like behavior, I write module, system picks up module and loads it properly. A gross simplification of how Spring does that though is, it loops over classes in the system in a specified package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Browserify  (via Detective) builds the dependency graph based on static analysis and therefore will only process `require()` calls with string literal arguments.